# condition is not assigning value to the variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am trying to assign the value to the variable if the conditions meets.however, php is still not setting the value. what am I doing wrong?

here is my php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['unit'])) {
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $query = search_by_unit($table, $unit);
    }
} else if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $query = select_all($table);
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

when I submit the form after setting unit control, it still runs select all function.

here are the functions:

```
function select_all($table_name){
      return "SELECT * FROM {$table_name}";
 }

function search_by_unit($table_name,$unit){
      return "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE unit = '{$unit}'";
 }
```

Comment: don't ever check the submit button value, directly check with form values.

Comment: it worked. thank you

Comment: you made it work but most of the time problem with testing submit stems from not setting name attribute for submit button. In fact there is not input for submit in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice at all to check submit button value. You have to check directly the `form Posted` value, So the code should be like below:-

```
if (isset($_POST['unit'])){
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $query = search_by_unit($table, $unit);
}else{
    $query = select_all($table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing more checks than you really need, or may want.  I'd reduce this code to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['unit'])) {
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $query = search_by_unit($table, $unit);
}
else {
    $query = select_all($table);
}
```

That way if `$_POST['submit']` is set but `$_POST['unit']` isn't, you'd still have a value for `$query`.